# How to implement V2I communication in veins omnet++?

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am trying to implement **V2I communication** in my veins scenario. The RSU sends a message that is a list containing the IDs of certain car nodes and only these cars must respond to the message. However, some of the car nodes are not in the range of the RSU when it sends the message. Hence, I am trying to make the cars reach the RSU through other RSUs in the network. How can I achieve this? Can someone please help me with this? I am using **veins 4.7.1, omnet 5.4.1 and sumo 0.32.0**.

Answer (score 1):

In very simple networks, each RSU may just forward all such messages to other RSUs. How that happens depends on how RSUs are connected among each other. Such forwarded messages would also need to carry the communication path they took to allow an answer to return to the original sender.

However, this may easily lead to flooding. So in bigger scenarios, you will need to build some kind of routing scheme, e.g., via neighbor tables. So the problem is probably less in the implementation in Veins but rather the protocol design.